# Manipulation Events Causing UI to Freeze or Become Slow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am working with multi-touch in order to allow a pinching action on an item. I have a `DispatchTimer` looping through a set of images, and when I pinch, I change out the current `Image` control (which I extended) so that it appears you are pinching the animation.

I have done all sorts of optimization, but I just cannot figure out why the animations freeze or get really slow while my fingers are moving on the screen. Even when I disabled everything but the image animation, moving my fingers still causes the same issue.

Also, when I have multiple animations using `DispatchTimer`, pinching on one of them freezes the rest. Is there something that I am missing? Why does the entire UI seem to freeze while I am touching on the screen?

My manipulation event that freezes the UI.

```
private void _ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Manipulators.Count() < 2) return;

    e.Handled = true;
    return;
}
```

**Update:** I find that the UI freezes even when an empty event handler is attached to the `ManipulationDelta` event and Manipulation is turned on.

Comment: elaborate the logic of e.Manipulators.Count() and the event wiring of _ManipulationDelta .. describe more details about the implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by optimizing my code outside of the Manipulation handler.

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless this behavior is a bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/782456/wpf-touch-event-fires-with-delay